# Pandas.plt how to show every label on x-axis containing dates

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to create a linechart using pandas.plt, but it does not show all the labels at each tick on the x-axis. I saw some solutions, but they weren't using Period's on the x-axis like I am doing. Is it possible to do this without variables fig, ax?

This is what I have:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

fig = tweets_per_month.plot(x = "month_year", legend= False, kind='line', figsize=(25, 8), fontsize = 15, grid = True, rot = 45).get_figure()
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('Number of tweets', fontsize=15)

fig.savefig('Tweet_count_REL2.png')
```

And this is an impression of my dataframe:
[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiUsB.png)

I now have this chart:
[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dc6Dg.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `plt.xticks(tweets_per_month['month_year'])` before saving the fig.

```
fig = tweets_per_month.plot(x = "month_year", legend= False, kind='line', figsize=(25, 8), fontsize = 15, grid = True, rot = 45).get_figure()
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('Number of tweets', fontsize=15)
plt.xticks(tweets_per_month['month_year'])

fig.savefig('Tweet_count_REL2.png')
```